# Any setting we can have to get notified when there's "something we have to review"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, review

I love to review posts! But I am really tired of keep coming back to my browser and refreshing that again and again to see if I have some posts to review? This sounds more annoying when I take some of my time to keep refreshing my page more than 5o times so frequently, and on recent reviewed tab gets updated but I don't find any thing on my plate to review.

Doesn't somebody think that we should have some thing that notifies us that we have something to review. Like in facebook in case of any notification they shows count of notifications as [image: facebook showing notifications]on the top of the page (on tab) so it's visible even if you are in another section of your browser.

I'm saying that this should be in all the case, but When I have left these pages

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts

etc. opened in my browser a badge indicating update should be displayed on the top of the tab, i.e.[image: Here].

Comment: I too would love this feature if it comes! The same thing which happens on question tags page /questions/tagged/<tagname>.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Items fly in and out of the queues so quickly, I don't see how this is remotely feasible; by the time you check the notification, the items could already be gone.

Not to mention, I imagine it would be an unnecessary and possibly large drain on system resources to send out notifications to **everyone** who has the privileges to review those items.

If I see a "First Post" item to review, by the time I click on the link, odds are it is already gone.  If you want to keep reviewing, just press <kbd>F5</kbd> or go back to the main review page.